# Get webpack chunkhash string inside React

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4

I'm using webpack 4 to create my chunks with chunkhashes, `chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'`, and I'm trying to figure out a way to get those hashes inside my React app.

I'm using `webpack-manifest-plugin` to generate a manifest file, and the file that's created contains JSON that looks like this:

`"about.js": "http://localhost:8500/static/about.62526fc2bee8e729ee44.js",`
, but obviously that file is created on build and I need to import into my React app.

Is there a way to get the chunkhashes as an `import`, or maybe some other way?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are trying to do please? Do you mean you are trying to figure out how to include the `script src=` tags for the manifest contents?

Comment: No, sorry. I need to get the hash values and make them available to a React component

Comment: I too would like to expose the 'chunkhash' of the webpack build via component to the end user, as a troubleshooting aide to determine if the user has a previously cached version or the latest known deploy.